# retrieving value of unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, std, unordered-map

I am reading contents of a .dat file and populating an unordered_map this way:

```
bool FileManager::LoadSkillList(LPCSTR name)
{
    int counter = 0;
    std::ifstream myFile(name, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out );
    if(myFile.fail())
    {
        myFile.close();
        return false;
    }
    char skill[0x12C];
    ZeroMemory(skill,0x12C);
    char buff[100];
    while(counter != TOTAL_SKILLS)
    {
        myFile.read(skill,0x12C);

        if(myFile.gcount() < 1) continue;

        auto skillBlock = (SkillInfo*)&skill;

#ifdef _DEBUG
        char* skillName = skillBlock->szSkillName;
        int delay = skillBlock->delayTime;

        wsprintf(buff,"Skill Name: %s - Delay: %d\r\n",skillName,delay);
        Log(buff);
#endif

        this->skills.insert(std::make_pair(counter,skillBlock));

        if(myFile.gcount() > 0) counter++;
        myFile.seekg( counter * 0x12C);
    }
#ifdef _DEBUG
    Log("Skill count: %d\r\n",(int)this->skills.size());
#endif
    myFile.close();

    return (counter>0)?true:false;
}
```

When I try to retrieve the map values inside the `LoadSkillList` method, it works fine. But I have another method in FileManager class, that is accessed by other class, in order to retrieve the unordered_map value.

```
for(int skillNumber = 0; skillNumber < TOTAL_SKILLS; skillNumber++)
{
    auto fileDelay = fManager->getDelay(skillNumber);
}
// ...

int FileManager::getDelay(int n)
{
    auto block = this->skills.at(n);
    return block->delayTime;
}
```

But somehow, my app crashs inside that method. (I am building an dll, and I checked it out with a debugger. )

Any clue of what is happening? Already tried with `std::array, std::map` with no success, both crash on the same method.

Comment: Could you please condense it to a **minimal, complete, self-contained** example?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? `.at()` can throw an out of range exception for example if `n` was an invalid index ...

Comment: I added a `try/catch` but it isnt even being triggered, the app crashs first

Comment: `auto skillBlock = (SkillInfo*)&skill;` is _really_ not what you want, given that `skill` is in automatic storage.

Comment: I just want to convert the `char[]` into my `struct` for a easier reading, and it does work indeed, I already tested, the issue is when I try to get the values using the `getDelay` method.

Comment: @lelejau : The problem is that you're pointing at local storage, which will be destroyed as soon as the function call ends (and each element is actually pointing at the same address, which clearly is not what you want).

Comment: Olly stops right after the `hash_compare` method. I tried `char* skill = new char[0x12C];` inside the file reading while-loop, without deleting it, but still not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem doing this:

declared `skills` as static.
Adding values to the `unordered_map` like this:

```
        FileManager::skills.insert(std::make_pair(counter, new SkillInfo()));
    memcpy(this->skills[counter],skillBlock,sizeof(SkillInfo));
```

Retrieving the desired value like this:

```
int FileManager::getDelay(int n)
{
auto block = FileManager::skills[n];
return block->delayTime;
}
```

Comment: A memcpy isn't a way to initialize a class in C++. try this: `FileManager::skills.insert(std::make_pair(counter, new SkillInfo(skillBlock)));`